# introversion and extroversion in Judaism

Tags: middos-character-traits

Is there anywhere in the Torah literature that discusses introversion and extroversion as being positive and/or negative traits? Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: Consider defining which aspects of these character traits you are referring to. After all, classical literature is hardly likely to use these terms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what your looking for, but the source i'm about to cite definitely leaves room for introversion (as defined by vocabulary.com "An introvert generally prefers solitary activities to interacting with large groups of people. If you would rather work through your feelings in your diary than have a conversation, then you are an introvert") in certain extreme circumstances, (רמב"ם יד החזקה - הלכות דעות פרק ו)

> דרך ברייתו של אדם להיות נמשך בדעותיו ובמעשיו אחר ריעיו וחביריו נווהג
>   נוהג
>    כמנהג אנשי מדינתו לפיכך צריך אדם להתחבר לצדיקים ולישב אצל החכמים תמיד
>   כדי שילמוד ממעשיהם ויתרחק מן הרשעים ההולכים בחשך כדי שלא ילמוד ממעשיהם
>   הוא ששלמה אומר הולך את חכמים יחכם ורועה כסילים ירוע ואומר אשרי האיש
>   וגו' וכן אם היה במדינה שמנהגותיה רעים ואין אנשיה הולכים בדרך ישרה ילך
>   למקום שאנשיה צדיקים ונוהגים בדרך טובים ואם היו כל המדינות שהוא יודעם
>   ושומע שמועתן נוהגים בדרך לא טובה כמו זמנינו או שאינו יכול ללכת למדינה
>   שמנהגותיה טובים מפני הגייסות או מפני החולי ישב לבדו יחידי כענין שנאמר
>   ישב בדד וידום ואם היו רעים וחטאים שאין מניחים אותו לישב במדינה אלא אם
>   כן נתערב עמהן ונוהג במנהגם הרע יצא למערות ולחוחים ולמדברות ואל ינהיג
>   עצמו בדרך חטאים כענין שנאמר מי יתנני במדבר מלון אורחים

The Rambam here maintains that a person's social life should consist of righteous and wise men and should avoid the wicked and foolish. However, if he cannot find a town inhabited by good people he must choose to live the life of an introvert. If this is not a choice either (they force him to socialize with them) he must live in the woods and deserts rather than continue living in a corrupt town.

I believe there is more on this, but i need to get my hands on them. For now this is the only source i have.

Comment: Sounds like actions taken, a life lead, rather than a character trait. The latter was asked about.

Comment: @msh210 The rambam included it in דעות which is all about character traits. If a person lives in seclusion for such a long time he becomes a different person and is rightfully called an introvert.